# SQLyog triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have a problem and I can't find the answer anywhere.

Can I write triggers like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER name BEFORE INSERT, UPDATE ON table...
```

or

```
CREATE TRIGGER name BEFORE INSERT, BEFORE UPDATE ON table...
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples

Comment: ok thanks that makes it clear, SOLVED